# Contact Form 7 wordpress, retrieving emails from database

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

Question in Contact Form 7 wordpress, is there a way to get the emails inputted by the visitor from the database? are the emails save in the database? thank you guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ramje,

Take a look at the following plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/

By default, when CF7 sends an email, the message is not stored to your database.

Comment: This plugin is no longer available for download, but it seems like a fork out there : https://wordpress.org/plugins/contactic/

Answer (score 2):

It seems that we have a plugin for storing Contact Form 7 information into DB made by the same team behind CF7. It's called Flamingo https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/

I made a step by step guide of the plugin and also showcased a few other alternatives to it https://deliciousthemes.com/save-contact-form-7-submissions-to-database/

One of the Flamingo downsides is that it can't store attachments too. However, there are solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this plugin **https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-advanced-database/**

It also has export and and search option at the backend.

Comment: Can you please explain why this will help OP with their issue?

Comment: Please don't post link only answers as links may break

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this plugin (it costs $16): http://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-database/14684587

You can export your emails (or any things) to csv file, maybe it can help you.

Comment: What about a free solution? And even if it is a paid one - would you care to explain this a bit more

Comment: I used some free plugins, but it seems not very good, complex. On the plugin on codecanyon, i can simply show/hide fields that i don't want to display, reorder fields by drag& drop... It saved me a lot of time. Any way, you can try free plugins, maybe they're useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hello Check out this New Plugin...! Its create input field as Column Name in Fields....!

https://wordpress.org/plugins/save-contact-form-7/

It help me out alot to update and add some field after form submission